# Thread makes activity crush while rotating

Tags: android, thread-safety, screen-orientation

I've got an activity that uses a thread in order to read a some content from a file.
The problem is that if the user decides to rotate the screen while the thread is running the application crushes. 
I know that I can prevent the screen from rotating using:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

But what I want to do is to stop the thread from running so the application can restart safely or prevent the activity from restarting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and stop it on the Activity.onPause() method.

On an important side node, setting the property `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` won't stop android from destroying and recreating the screen on a change of the orientation, it will just don't display a landscape mode.

Comment: I just tried using `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` and  I think it did prevent android from recreating the screen.

Comment: I'll be honest, I've never forced an orientation, but in the book *The Busy Coders Guide To Android Development*, section *Handling Rotation -> Forcing the Issue* states that "Android will *still* destroy and recreate your activity, even if you have the orientation set to a specific value" (I hope [CommonsWare](http://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) doesn't mind that I copied that phrase from his book).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this to the activity declaration in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your thread holding references to UI objects like buttons? If so, because the rotation destroys and recreates the activity, you'll be referencing the old objects, not the new ones. That's why it's necessary to destroy and recreate the thread or asynctask.

Comment: I don't mind recreating the thread, the problem is that application is crushing when I try to do that.

Answer (score -1):

When user rotates the device, your application is restarted in that process the method onDestroy is called. So you can use Activity.onDestroy method to destroy/stop your thread.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html there you can find stop, destroy, interrumpt and other methods, not sure what of them should be used right now.

Comment: Another think you can do is to manage the activity orientation by itself, check this out:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html